# Creating a forensic copy of a drive with multiple partitions of different file types

Tags: dd, computer-forensics

I have a small 80GB drive with three partitions, two FAT and one NTFS. Using FTKImager and dd-for-windows (http://www.chrysocome.net/dd), I need to create a forensic copy of this drive.

The only dd command I've been taught so far is:

`C:\windows\system32>[location of dd.exe] if=[location of raw image dump] of=\\.\[letter path of the copy drive]`

This can be used to turn a drive\partition into a forensic copy of a single partition if the drive is already using the same file system as the one its copying. To do this task just using this command, I'd have to partition the copy drive three times, make three image dumps and dd each partition-image pair individually. This seems tedious and wouldn't even create a true forensic copy of the original drive.

Is there a way to make a raw image of the original drive as a whole, and a dd command that will turn a second drive into a copy of the first from that image?

Thank you

Comment: Please note that `m` is the SI prefix for `milli` and `b` is the SI unit for `bits`, so you are saying your drive is 80 millibits. I have edited your post on the assumption you meant 80GB, i.e. 80 gigabytes.

Comment: Hello Caleb. We either need more information or perhaps some clarification. For example, FTK Imager can make a forensic image of any full drive or individual partitions by itself... using DD isn't necessary in this case. FTK Imager can also open/view the created image(s), view it's partitions if it has any, and mount them for further examination.  Is there some particular reason you need/want to use DD? If it's only to write a copy of the original drive, you could use a tool like OSFClone to do that, which is DD with some other tools: https://www.osforensics.com/tools/create-disk-images.html

Answer (score 0):

Nothing easier than that! Just boot a Live Linux system e.g. Ubuntu, Debian or Kali then you go into the terminal ...

With fdisk -l you display the disk, look where your disk (80GB) is ... I will now start from /dev/sdb. Then you look where you want the dump to go, e.g. to an external disk with a partition that has enough space, which is assumed to be /dev/sdc1 here, then you can write the disk to an image ... for that you mount the target. I now assume a third disk /dev/sdd which should contain the clone

`mkdir /tmp/mount`

`mount /dev/sdc1 /tmp/mount`

and write the desired record into an image

`dd if=/dev/sdb of=/tmp/mount/image.dd`

Now you can copy the disk directly or through the image.dd to another one, but the target /dev/sdd (your clone disk) must not be mounted anymore! you can check with "mount" and remount everything before

`dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdd #Direct copy`

`dd if=/tmp/image.dd of=/dev/sdd #From the image.dd to a disk`

Hope this helps